# Multiple Columns in Crystal Report at runtime

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a crystal report with the option "Format with Multiple Columns" checked. In the "Layout" tab I've manually set the width of the column, but the actual width of the column will only be determined at runtime.

So, is it possible to change the width of the column at runtime?

I am using Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0 on Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Comment: Crystal Report does not support design update at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of growing the width of the column keep the width constant to some value and check the `can grow` option so that your data will be displayed when the data in the column is exceding.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
TextObject MyText = (TextObject)reportdocument.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects[i];

MyText.Width =Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text.ToString());
```